# SQL return only entries where data in another other table isn't the same

Tags: sql, join

I am currently working between two tables "CustomerInfo" and "CustomerPayment"

In the "CustomerInfo" table I have both a "CustomerNumber" field and "CustomerType"

- The CustomerNumber links the customer to the correct entries in the "CustomerPayment" table

I am trying to pull out a report of customers that show as "CustomerType" being "Credit" in the "CustomerInfo"  table but don't show as having a "Credit" entry in the "CustomerPayment" table under the "PaymentType" field, I am matching the two table based on CustomerInfo.CustomerNumber = CustomerPayment.CustomerNumber.

I have tried a couple of basic joins etc but I am unable to get an accurate report showing "Credit" customers that have no "Credit" payments present on their records.

I wasn't sure if it would be possible to somehow do a NOT EXISTS clause perhaps?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This sounds like `not exists`:

```
select ci.*
from customerinfo ci
where ci.customertype = 'credit' and
      not exists (select 1
                  from CustomerPayment cp
                  where cp.customernumber = ci.customernumber and
                        cp.paymenttype = 'credit'
                  );
```

Answer (score 0):

A LEFT JOIN with a NULL test could also do it:

```
SELECT * FROM CustomerInfo
LEFT JOIN CustomerPayment 
ON CustomerInfo.CustomerNumber = CustomerPayment.CustomerNumber 
AND CustomerPayment.PaymentType = 'CREDIT'
WHERE CustomerPayment.CustomerNumber IS NULL
```